# Is it possible for fread() or fwrite() to return a value greater than the number of items? Why?

Tags: c

Reading through https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread , I noticed that the result of fread() is compared with `==`. I saw people use `<` before, so the obvious question presented itself of whether the error value can be MORE than the number of items that were asked of the function?

The man page for fread/fwrite says:

> If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).

This is a strong implication that it might be true, but I would prefer a more official confirmation if possible, or at least a confirmation that what the man page says can be taken seriously.

Comment: Re “This is a strong implication that it might be true”: Hmm? How do you figure that “the return value is a short item count” implies “the item count might be longer, not shorter, than requested”?

Comment: returning a value greater then the number of items passed would mean that more items are read/written then requested. Hard to imagine ..

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: I can imagine it, hypothetically. Suppose the underlying physical storage device of a stream uses 512-byte blocks, the stream is positioned at the beginning of a block, and the program requests 10 4-byte items. The program has to read 40 bytes, which means it has to read 512 bytes. It could make sense to provide the caller with the 40 bytes they requested and inform them a total of 128 such items are available at no additional cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[§7.21.8.1 ¶3 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.8.1p3) states the following:

> The fread function returns the number of elements successfully read, which may be less than nmemb if a read error or end-of-file is encountered.

Therefore, the return value will never exceed the value of the `nmemb` function argument (which is the third function argument).

Answer (score 2):

You do not give a citation for this text:

> If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).

It is not in the [*C++ reference* page you link to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread). It is in the [die.net page for `fread`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) and in the macOS 10.14.6 `man` page for `fread`. However, these pages are imprecisely written. For example, they say “The function **fread**() reads *nmemb* elements of data,…” which is of course wrong in general. More precisely and correctly, `fread` **attempts** to read *nmemb* elements of data. It stops when an error occurs.

In any case, `fread` will not read more elements than requested, and therefore it will not return a result greater than the `nmemb` argument.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for `fread()` or `fwrite()` to return a value greater than the number of items?

**Correctly typed arguments**

No, as others well explained.

---

**Incorrectly typed arguments**

With poorly typed code, it can seem like a value greater than the number of items.

```
char buf[255];

// With signed char, `number_of_items` may equal -1
char number_of_items = sizeof buf;

// Passing -1 to `fread()` is like passing `SIZE_MAX`.
// Code experiences UB reading more than 255 characters.
size_t number_read = fread(buf, 1, number_of_items, stream);

if (number_read > sizeof buf) {
  puts("Oops");
}
```